# Query builder laravel with and select

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

I want to show "cars.name" in result.
I need to use "cars.name" value to order later

```
$this->model
        ->select("pieces.*", "cars.name")
        ->where('cars_id', $carId)
        ->with('cars')
        ->has('cars', '>=', 1);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to join your `cars` table in order to select columns from that separate table in this query. https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#joins

Comment: As @jszobody said use a join. If you insist on using Eloquent relationships you have to show us more code and maybe share a piece of the database diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it this way by passing a closure function in `with()`:

```
$this->model
        ->select("pieces.*")
        ->where('cars_id', $carId)
        ->with('cars'=> function ($query) {
             $query->select('id','name');
        }])
        ->has('cars', '>=', 1);
```

It will only select id and username from other table.

**Remember that the primary key (id in this case) needs to be the first param in the $query->select() to actually retrieve the necessary results.**

Answer (score 0):

the first you have built is just a query, then it needs to be retrieved on the server, use get() and you will see error message. Need more info about the relation between pieces and cars to help. Try it -

```
$this->model::whereHas('cars',function(builder $query)use($cardId){
$query->where('cars_id', $carId);})->has('cars', '>=', 1)->with('cars')->get();
then obtain cars name via denamic property of a relation
```